# serving static JSON files on azure

Tags: azure, sencha-touch

I've made a simple Sencha Touch web application and deployed it to Azure to try Azure out.  One of the first things Sencha Touch does is try to download an app.json file.  On IIS I'd normally enable json in the mime types section, but I have not been able how to figure this out how to do this using the Azure Web Console.  Consequently, a 404 error is returned when the app performs an XMLHttpRequest to get the file.

I've seen some post on SO about adding .json to the web.config and I tried the following, to no avail:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"  />
    </staticContent>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

The web app is here.

http://nsgapp.azurewebsites.net

Any input on how to enable an Azure shared-instance to serve .json files is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, it was a silly error.  I have two websites... one that serves the sencha web app and an ASP.NET MVC WebAPI site for the webservices.  I was enabling json on the latter, when I should have been enabling it on the former because app.json is in served from the actual client application.  So, the correct way to enable azure to download static json files is to make sure you have this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"  />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

in the web.config.

Comment: I had to change the Build Action (In properties) of app.json and cache.appcache to Content. Also add following to staticContent 

<mimeMap fileExtension=".appcache" mimeType="text/cache-manifest" />